# How to remind the HR for the interview?

Tags: interviewing

I applied for a job at a tech company. First, I was given a online assessment, which I cleared. After that HR sent an email stating that I have been selected for further rounds of interviews and asked me about a date on which I can attend it. I replied back with the date but since then I haven't received any email or calendar invite. How should I follow up?

Comment: Can you indicate what timeframes we are talking about here?

Comment: How long have you been waiting? And how long until the date you gave?

Answer (score 4):

> How should I follow up?

Not at all, it's waste of time and highly unlikely to do any good. Just keep looking and applying elsewhere.

Interviews fall off the radar ALL THE TIME. Job got filled,  budget got shifted, a more important hire takes priority, recruiter got reassigned or fired, the whole team got re-orged out of existence, blatant incompetence & disorganization, etc. etc. etc.

Whatever the reason is, you reaching out is unlikely to make any difference at all since it won't address any of the reasons above (other than maybe incompetence).

Just don't get your hopes up and keep looking and applying. If the interview still happens: Great? If not: no harm done, that's just the reality of it. You have to kiss a lot of frogs to find your prince/ss.

Answer (score 2):

If it's been a few days since you responded with a date that works for you, or not many days until that date, then send a polite email asking them if the date you've proposed works for them as well, or if you need to make sure you can be available on a different day.

In my opinion it's perfectly appropriate to follow up if they haven't confirmed a date, and it's more than likely to have fallen through the cracks on their end.

If it's fallen off their radar then there's no downside to you for following up. If they decide you look pushy or desperate then why would that be worse than having no chance at all of getting the job?

It also has essentially no cost (a minute or two writing an email), so to me following up is a no-brainer, even if there's a low chance that it changes anything. Adjust the odds into your favour as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of knowing the time frames we're talking about...  I wouldn't follow-up at all.

If the interview has fallen off of their radar then what else could potentially fall off their radar? Could raises fall off their radar as well?

If the interview hasn't fallen off of their radar then you potentially come off as being impatient.

Comment: *"Then what else could potentially fall off their radar? Could raises fall off their radar as well?"*  That is the most chilling sentence I have read on the whole site.  Terrifying indeed.